# How to show two different categories in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Actually i've a static website and i'm trying to convert it into wordpress, i'm new to wordpress. I have successfully created following page.

`header.php`
`footer.php`
`sidebar.php`
`functions.php`
`index.php`

Then i have created a `main-template.php` page for my other pages like about, contact, gallery, etc, They will all be using same template. The website is almost completed but only two pages are left.

`1. Jobs`

`2. News & Events`

So in these pages, There will be new jobs coming, and same for news & events. So i think these two pages will be like a blog post.

Jobs page will display all the jobs with title and 100 words description and read more button, Then it will open in new page for that particular job.

I have will different job categories like `electrician`, `plumber`,`mason`,`english language`,`call center` etc

I want to show all categories jobs on Jobs page.

So I have created a Page in `wp-admin>pages>add new` called `Jobs` and `newsEvents` and selected template `main-template` that i have used for all pages. But this page will be blog type to show all jobs.

As you know I will be having two blog type pages one for JObs and one for News Events So I have only created two categories `Jobs` & `NewsEvents`

Now If i add a new job, I will go to `wp-admin>posts>add New` then add title, description, select category Job if it is job, similarly for newsevents.

**So the question is How do i show jobs on jobs page and newsevents on newsevents page?**

**How to create single.php?**

**How many single.php do i have to create?**

```
I have created `single.php`
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Jobs
 */
/*get_header();*/
get_header();
?>
<?php

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', 'Jobs' );
endwhile;
?>
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

and I have created Empty jobs page in wp-admin>pages>Job its link is `localhost/MyProject/jobs` I want to show jobs on this page, all jobs that i will post..

I have created `content-jobs.php` page too, Now what should i do next? how will i show jobs?
`my content-jobs.php`

```
    <?php the_content() ?>
```

I have already read wordpress documentation but unable to understand properly, this is my first time doing it, Help me?

Answer (score 0):

1) you need create separate template for these pages.
2) Create the pages with receptive names
3) Use these templates on these pages in admin
4) Create custom post type News& Events

```
  add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'News',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'News' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'News' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}
```

add this code in function.php

after that post some data in this post type
and to show this on front end in your template file use.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'News', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  the_title();
  echo '<div class="entry-content">';
  the_content();
  echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

use this it will help you

Comment: Im confused So There are two type of posts, `Jobs` and `News`. Do i have to add the code two times in `function.php` for Jobs and News?

Comment: Yes if you want to show these different different pages you need create two types of post type Jobs and News.

Comment: I have created two types of page, but how to do like this, my new post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227783/how-to-add-show-new-fields-in-posts-in-wordpress